# focus out for all elements in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form that contains 10 input fields (not all are included below). I am trying to fire event with the jQuery `focusout` function. For instance, the form name is: `form_test`

```
<form id="form_test">
    <input name="customer_id" id="customer_id" hidden>
    <input name= "customer_name" id= "customer_name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Company Name">
</form>
```

What I would like to happen is no matter which input box they click away from, after they do, the focusout event would happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `focusout` event will fire every time an `input` is focused and then the focus is removed. The snippet below represents how you can bind to that event.

```js
$(function() {

  // Using the id
  $("#form_test input").on('focusout', function() {
    console.log("focusout event triggered using the id!");
  });

  // Using the name
  $("form[name='form_test'] input").on('focusout', function() {
    console.log("focusout event triggered using the name!");
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form_test" id="form_test">
  <input name="customer_id" id="customer_id" hidden>
  <input name="customer_name" id="customer_name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Company Name">
</form>
```

Comment: I want to set focus though on input elements ONLY under form_test, otherwise this will happen for all input fields and I only want to achieve this for one specific form.

Comment: @datasci I have updated my answer with two options. I do suggest that you target using the name for something like this, but using an `id` is certainly possible as well.

Answer (score 0):

Target our specific form by ID and use the `:input` selector:

```js
$('#form_test').on('focusout', ':input', function() {
  console.log('OUT!')
});
```

```html
<form id="form_test">
    <input name="customer_id" id="customer_id" hidden>
    <input name= "customer_name" id= "customer_name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Company Name">
    <textarea name="msg">Works for textarea too</textarea>
    <select name="sel"><option>and here too</option></select>
</form>


<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

> https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/
>   Selects all input, textarea, select and button elements.
>   *The `:input` selector basically selects all form controls.*